# laravel aldap2 импорт новых пользователей без обновления старых

Tags: laravel, ldap

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.
Хочу запустить планировщик, который бы запускался импортировал новых пользователей без изменения старых - уже имеющихся в базе.

```
$schedule->command('adldap:import', [
        '--no-interaction',
        '--filter' => '(objectclass=user)',
])->everyThirtyMinutes();
```

Возможно в библиотеки нет соответствующего ключа? И тогда придется искать всех новых пользователей через модель Adldap.
Например как-то так

```
$schedule->call(function () {
        $user = User::last(); // Находим последнего импортированного ранее пользователя
        Adldap::search()->where('id', '>', $user['id'])->get(); //поиск пользователей, которых нужно добавить
        foreach($newUsers as $user){
                User:create() // добавляем новых пользователей.
        }
})->everyThirtyMinutes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится.

```
$schedule->call(function () {
      $users = Adldap::search()->users()->get();
      foreach($users as $user){
          if (!$this->searchUser($user->objectguid[0])){ // Проверяем существование пользователя в нашей модели User через objectguid.
             User::create([]); // добавляем пользователя с нужными полями
          }
       }
})->daily();
```